# IP camera acessing using rtsp, visual studio OpenCv 2.4.5?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

This is the code used to access my IP camera using lan port. (first code works fine). What I need is to get image with Mat(C++) structure. Code number 2 shows what I have done to using Mat structure but when I debug the program, execute cv::namedWindow("Frame"); and then breaks the code giving out an Unhandled exception which shows bellow.
My Final requirement is to get this job done using Mat instead of iplimage. tip or an appropriate code would be great since I am doing a project on Human detection using HOG. thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv.hpp"

int main(){

CvCapture *camera=cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://192.168.1.19:554/0/1:1/main");
if (camera==NULL)
printf("camera is null\n");
else
printf("camera is not null");

cvNamedWindow("img");
while (cvWaitKey(10)!=atoi("q")){

IplImage *img=cvQueryFrame(camera);
cvShowImage("img",img);
}
cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
}
```

code number 2 :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        cv::Ptr<CvCapture> capture = cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://192.168.1.19:554/0/1:1/main");
        cv::namedWindow("Frame");
        for (;;)
        {
            cv::Mat frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0)
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Exception :
Unhandled exception at 0x00660598 in Hog with Web cam.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccc0065.

Answer (score 0):

yea, get rid of the darn c-api !

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        cv::namedWindow("Frame");
        cv::VideoCapture capture("rtsp://192.168.1.19:554/0/1:1/main");
        while ( capture.isOpened() )     // check !!
        {
            cv::Mat frame;
            if ( ! capture.read(frame) ) // another check !!
                break;

            cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0)
                break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "rtsp://192.168.1.19:554/0/1:1/main" this is my ip address and its password protected. This was taken from the user manual of the camera. apparently it was given to stream rtsp in vlc so to use this with cv::VideoCapture vcap; do i need to change the format or add a dummy tail ? any tip thanks.

Comment: Becuase I have tried with this code and it does not capture any frame from the camera. camera seems to be null.

Comment: Have you tried placing the opencv_ffmpeg248.dll in your output directory?